# Connotation of 年季の入った when describing things

Tags: meaning

I encountered the following line in volume 2 of ハクメイとミコチ:

> 鋭い目付きの男は、年季の入った道具を携え卓越した技術を振るった。

How does 年季の入った characterize the tools the man used? Does it mean that they are reliable tools that stood the test of time, or just old worn-out tools?

Comment: Is 年季の入った{{道具を携え卓越した}技術} a possible interpretation? https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/170895/meaning/m0u/

Comment: ^ ううん。。「年季（年期？）の入った道具」ですね。。　『年期の入った ... 一般的には「年季の入った」と書く。「年季の入った」とは、**物が良く使い込まれているさま**、あるいは非常に腕が熟練しているさまなどを意味する表現。』 https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B9%B4%E6%9C%9F%E3%81%AE%E5%85%A5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

年季の入った道具 means it's an old and well-used tool. That is, the tool has worked sufficiently for a long time at least for this man, but this phrase does not directly say it's a high-quality tool in a general sense. For example, even a very cheap hammer can be 年季の入ったハンマー if someone used it for a long time.

**EDIT**: To clarify, when 年季の入った modifies a person or an action, it tends to have a positive connotation similar to 円熟/熟練. But when 年季の入った modifies an inanimate object, I think it just refers to something that has been used for a long time and is showing its age, but is still perfectly usable. Depending on the context, it may have a value as a vintage, though.  See [this thesaurus entry](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B9%B4%E5%AD%A3%E3%81%AE%E5%85%A5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F), too.

Comment: (なにが悪いのかさっぱり分からない…「年季の入った投球」とかならいわゆる熟練の技のことかもしれませんが、「年季の入ったグローブ」「年季の入った財布」は別に高級品である必要はないですよね…？)